# Get sunday of last week on the month with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

How I can get sunday of last week on the month with Carbon?

```
$startDate = Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();
$lastSunday = $startDate()->endOfWeek();
```

Not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Carbon like this:

```
Carbon::parse('last sunday of this month')
```

This will return Carbon instance with the last Sunday of current month.

Comment: No. I need get Sunday of current last month. But if month January? I need go to controller and edit this line? Change december on January?